# downloading quaqua look and feel to integrate with the java application in windows

Tags: java, windows, look-and-feel, quaqua

where can i download quaqua look and feel for java app in *windows*? What are the steps to integrate this look and feel with  the project ?

I want to integrate this look and feel with my java application on *windows*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/ FAQ

Can I use Quaqua on other platforms than Mac OS X?
No, you can't, except for development purposes. 
This is because the Aqua user interface can only be licensed from Apple for use on Mac OS X.

Anyhow, for development purposes only, here's a guide for using the Quaqua L&F:

http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/guide/index.html

Comment: what do you mean by _"except for development purposes"_ ?

Comment: "He" means that you can develop using quaqua but you can't deploy an application (free or commercial) that uses it.

Comment: and where can i download the quaqua for development purposes ?

Comment: it doesn't tell how to get the quaqua jar file

Comment: click on the first link, come on!